# How to pivot the following JOIN query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am attempting to pass data from database to Google charts, however, Google charts has a specific way in which it excepts data. For this reason, I need to change the following output:

[image: current output]

to this :

[image: wanted output]

the query for the original output is:

```
SELECT (select COUNT(projects.funding)from projects where funding > 0)as  Funding, 
SUM(projects.mreq = 'yes') Mentor_Required, 
SUM(projects.tmreq = 'yes') Team_Member_Required 
FROM projects INNER JOIN users ON projects.members = users.email 
WHERE users.company = 'vit'
```

The 2 tables are:
projects

[image: projects table]

users

[image: users table]

Would love some guidance on putting pivot on the above query or any better method.

Comment: Why does the title say UNION, when there's no UNION in the query?

Comment: Apologies, I fixed the title

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and PIVOT is implemented differently in different database products. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: mysql, added tag

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just do:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN p.mreq = 'yes' THEN 'Mentor_Required'
             WHEN p.tmreq = 'yes' THEN 'Team_Member_Required'
        END) as Funding,
       COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM projects p INNER JOIN
     users u
     ON p.members = u.email 
WHERE u.company = 'vit' 
GROUP BY Funding;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, however this resulted in :

column names as Funding  &  cnt & data as
Mentor_Required       =1
NULL                         =1
Mentor Required  =1

What i need is, count of number of "yes" in mreq , count of number of "yes" in tmreq & count of number of values greater than 0 in funding.
I played around with your query & found that case will stop executing when the first statement is "true", however all my statements are expected to be "true". What would be a better way to use case?